# Which protective spell reduces the damage the caster sustains the most without hindering the gameplay?

Tags: two-worlds-2

I found the mana shield spell that redirects incoming damage to my mana but I read that this shield makes my mana regeneration 3 times slower (same amount every 3 seconds or 1/3 every second) while active and it has an extremely short duration...

I don't like the tornado shield as it picks up everything in my path (including dead bodies, yuck) and all the debris hinders our co-op in multiplayer.

I've seen a +resist all spell but it looked pretty expensive mana-wise.

---

water + enchant + damage + time + protection

- increases resistance to all damage by xx% for yy sec.

Does this include physical and spell dmg?
Is there a better/cheaper alternative that doesn't mess with my game experience?

Comment: You've mentioned at least two protective spells already, so clearly there are some. Are you asking what the "best" one is? What metrics are important to you when determining what's "best"?

Comment: I made an edit. I'm looking for a spell that protects me (and maybe my partner) without messing with my game experience by throwing stuff around or draining my mana.